# Why do I get a syntax error with this simple python math equation

Tags: python

I just started to learn python and I've been playing around with coderunner by making up various equations to help me learn.

Here's the equation I wrote

```
def mission(x):
    total = []
    for i in x:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            z = i**2 + 20
        else i % 2 == 1:
            y = i**3 + 30
        total.append(y)
        total.append(z)
    return total

print mission([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9])
```

here's the error i keep getting:

```
  File "Untitled 2.py", line 6
  else i % 2 == 1:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is really frustrating because it's such an easy task but I get an error for a reason I don't know.

Can someone please explain.
Thanks

Comment: Try `elif i % 2 == 1:`

Comment: Please read the chapter about `if`, `else` etc. again.

Comment: replace `else` to `elif`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test the result of `i%2` in the `else` statement. It should just be:

```
else:
```

If an integer isn't even then it must be odd, there's no need to test for that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Eh... replace..

```
else i % 2 == 0:
```

With...

```
elif i % 2 == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by earlier commentators, try [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) first.

That said, the short answer is you can't test anything in the `else` part of of the `if` statement.  If you need to make multiple tests, use `elif`.
 e.g.

```
if i % 3 == 1:
    # do something
elif i % 3 == 2:
    # do something else
else:
    # do the other thing if neither is true
```

Comment: How could neither be true? Are you using a version of math where there's something other then even and odd integers?

Comment: @Barmar -- insufficient editing on my part in preparing the example.  Yes, the `else` would never be executed in the original example, but i've now updated it to make sense.  Thanks.